# Whats the difference between these date where-clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

These two queries return different order counts and it's not entirely clear as to why. The first `where` clause is the accepted `correct` version:

```
where
year(OrderDate) = 2011
and MONTH(OrderDate) = 8
and DAY(OrderDate) = 3
```

but if I say something very similar:

```
WHERE 
io.OrderDate >= '2011-08-03 00:00:00' 
and io.OrderDate <= '2011-08-03 11:59:59'
```

I get a completely different record count. Is there something I'm doing wrong in date formatting or is there something I'm missing in logic? I'd prefer to say the latter as it's a little easier to use IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

The new answer I would recommend combines my original (as displayed below) with the comments made by Mikael and Alex.

```
WHERE 
io.OrderDate >= '2011-08-03 00:00:00' 
and io.OrderDate < '2011-08-04 00:00:00'
```

Should provide the desired result.

---

The second query is only looking from Midnight to Noon. (00:00:00 - 11:59:59 is twelve hours)

```
WHERE 
io.OrderDate >= '2011-08-03 00:00:00' 
and io.OrderDate <= '2011-08-03 23:59:59'
```

Should fix it.

@Alex answer has a point as well. Milliseconds count (depending on whether or not your particular table includes them).

```
WHERE 
io.OrderDate >= '2011-08-03 00:00:00.000' 
and io.OrderDate <= '2011-08-03 23:59:59.999'
```

Would include any additional records missed

Comment: You should try this `select cast('2011-08-03 23:59:59.999' as datetime)`. Your second version will include rows where OrderDate is `2011-08-04 00:00:00`

Comment: @Mikael, Rather than cast, I'll just change it to the method your answer recommends.

Comment: @Sam - I did not mean that you should change to cast. That was only do show that a datetime with ms = 999 will round to the next day.

Comment: @Mikael, Ah, I misunderstood you. If I remember correctly, this is because SQL (Server at least) stores datetimes with 3ms precision?

Comment: @Sam - Yes that is correct. If you used ms=998 it would round to 997 instead.

Answer (score 4):

Well, 11:59:59 is just before midday (that's 11 *am* you're referrring to), which means you're missing 12 hours.

Also, keep in mind that you can also specify milliseconds in your DateTime. So you could have `'2011-08-03 23:59:59.100'`, which is after your specified max OrderDate (even after correcting for 24 hour time)

Answer (score 4):

You should do it like this.

```
WHERE 
io.OrderDate >= '2011-08-03 00:00:00' 
and io.OrderDate < '2011-08-04 00:00:00'
```

Apart from the fact that the rowcount is different in your queries, the first will not be able to use any index on OrderDate column.